# Send a query to a model repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please help. I am new in ASP.NET MVC and I am trying to send a query to a repository but it gives me an error:

> Errr 3 Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I am using a a Schema Class with only the columns that I need. This is the code that I am using for the repository.

```
public class SSGridRepository : SSGridIRepository
{
    private DataClassesSSDataContext db;

    public SSGridRepository()
    {
        db = new DataClassesSSDataContext();
    }

    public IList<SSQuerySchema> ListAll()
    {

        var SSQuery = (from HISTORies in db.HISTORies
                       join SSes in db.SSes on HISTORies.WO equals SSes.WO
                       join SSCUSTOMs in db.SSCUSTOMs on SSes.WO equals SSCUSTOMs.WO
                       join StatusTables in db.StatusTables on new { STATUS = SSes.STATUS } equals new { STATUS = StatusTables.Status }
                       join StatusTable_1 in db.StatusTables on new { OLDSTATUS = HISTORies.OLDSTATUS } equals new { OLDSTATUS = StatusTable_1.Status }
                       join StatusTable_2 in db.StatusTables on new { NEWSTATUS = HISTORies.NEWSTATUS } equals new { NEWSTATUS = StatusTable_2.Status }
                       where
                         HISTORies.OLDSTATUS == "m" &&
                         HISTORies.NEWSTATUS == "n" &&
                         HISTORies.ACTION == "Change Job Status" &&
                         HISTORies.OLDSTATUS != HISTORies.NEWSTATUS &&
                         HISTORies.DATE.Value.Year == Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).Year ||
                         HISTORies.OLDSTATUS != HISTORies.NEWSTATUS &&
                         HISTORies.NEWSTATUS == "m" &&
                         HISTORies.ACTION == "Checked In Work Order" &&
                         HISTORies.DATE.Value.Year == Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).Year
                       orderby
                         HISTORies.DATE
                       select new
                       {
                           HISTORies.WO,
                           SSes.TITLE,
                           SSes.DESCRIPT,
                           SSCUSTOMs.CUSTNAME,
                           SSes.STAKER,
                           HISTORies.USER,
                           SSes.STATUS,
                           HISTORies.OLDSTATUS,
                           HISTORies.NEWSTATUS,
                           CURRENT_STATUS = StatusTables.Description,
                           OLD_STATUS = StatusTable_1.Description,
                           NEW_STATUS = StatusTable_2.Description,
                           HISTORies.DATE.Value.Month,
                           HISTORies.DATE
                       }).Distinct();
        return SSQuery.ToList();
    }        
}
```

Comment: The error is in the last line. SSQuery.ToList();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you Linq you do this:

```
select new  {
                           HISTORies.WO,
                           SSes.TITLE,
                           SSes.DESCRIPT,
                           SSCUSTOMs.CUSTNAME,
                           SSes.STAKER,
                           HISTORies.USER,
                           SSes.STATUS,
                           HISTORies.OLDSTATUS,
                           HISTORies.NEWSTATUS,
                           CURRENT_STATUS = StatusTables.Description,
                           OLD_STATUS = StatusTable_1.Description,
                           NEW_STATUS = StatusTable_2.Description,
                           HISTORies.DATE.Value.Month,
                           HISTORies.DATE
                       }
```

Which is a dynamic type so it wont match you return type of `List<SSQuerySchema>`

Try initializing the type you have specified in your Linq and set the properties of course.

```
  select new SSQuerySchema {
                               // initialize all properties here
                           }
```

Comment: You need to explicitly specify the property names if you use an initializer.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to return an `IList<SSQuerySchema>` but your actual return type is `IList<dynamic>` (Your not selecting `SSQuerySchema`'s but an anonymous type.

You should either make the return type of the function `IList<dynamic>` or modify your select to create new instances of `SSQuerySchema`